# Slick access to DataSource Programmatically

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have a object like this :

```
object DatabaseFactory {

  import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._

  private val db = Database.forConfig("database.postgresql")

  def getDatabase = db
}
```

and a configuration like this :

```
database {
    postgresql {
      connectionPool = "HikariCP"
      dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
      properties = {
          serverName = "localhost"
          portNumber = "5432"
          databaseName = "myProject"
          user = "user"
          password = "userPass"
      }
      numThreads = 10
    }
}
```

There is any way to get javax.sql.DataSource from slick ?
I need a instance of **PGSimpleDataSource** from slick .

I want to use that on Flyway configuration :

```
Flyway.configure()
      .baselineOnMigrate(true)
      .locations("filesystem:/etc/myProject/db-scripts")
      .dataSource(??? Need DataSource ???)
```

Comment: https://github.com/nafg/slick-migration-api-flyway

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled upon this and seen the comment by https://stackoverflow.com/users/337134/knows-not-much . 
Basically, you'll need to implement your own instance of Datasource:

```
package slick.migration.api.flyway

import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.sql.{DriverManager, SQLException, SQLFeatureNotSupportedException}

import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend

import javax.sql.DataSource


class DatabaseDatasource(database: JdbcBackend#Database) extends DataSource {
  override def getConnection = database.createSession().conn
  override def getConnection(username: String, password: String) = throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
  override def unwrap[T](iface: Class[T]) =
    if (iface.isInstance(this)) this.asInstanceOf[T]
    else throw new SQLException(getClass.getName + " is not a wrapper for " + iface)
  override def isWrapperFor(iface: Class[_]) = iface.isInstance(this)
  override def getLogWriter = throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
  override def setLogWriter(out: PrintWriter): Unit = throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
  override def setLoginTimeout(seconds: Int): Unit = DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(seconds)
  override def getLoginTimeout = DriverManager.getLoginTimeout
  override def getParentLogger = throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is any way to get javax.sql.DataSource from slick ?

I don't think so but I was able to get an instance of slick.jdbc.JdbcDataSource which I then used the exact same way i always used javax.sql.DataSource. creating connection, then preparedstatement, then handling a resultset. all the same.

```
db.source
```

I know this is old but wanted to give an option to try that isn't as drastic as the other answer of creating your own instance of datasource.